# Override a submit type button to call custom javascript method instead

Tags: javascript, form-submit, code-injection, submit-button

I cannot alter the following code, but instead must override the default functionality of the button so that when clicked, a custom javascript method is called instead of the form being submitted.

And to accomplish this I must use javascript via injection.(Its a AIR desktop app using the twitter api)

Can anyone help?

```
<body>
<form><fieldset class="buttons">
           <input class="submit button" id="cancel" name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<body>
```

Comment: Why not start by changing the type from `submit` to `button`.

Comment: Are you asking how to do injection or about `event.preventDefault()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent form from submitting overiding click wont be enough. One can submit you form by Ctrl+Enter.

You can do the following http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/R5yQq/.

1. Find the form assuming you know button id.

   ```
   function getForm(id) {

        var button = document.getElementById(id);

        while(button && 
             (button = button.parentNode) && 
             (button.nodeName !== 'FORM')){}

        return button;
   }
   ```
2. Add 'submit' event listener.

   ```
   var form = getForm('cancel'),
       handler = function(ev){
       ev = ev || window.event;
       if(ev.preventDefault) { //w3c browsers
           ev.preventDefault();    
       }
       else { //IE old
           ev.returnValue = false;    
       }
       alert('Custom logic goes here!'); 
   };
   if(form) {
       if(form.addEventListener) {
          form.addEventListener('submit', handler, false)   
       }
       else if(form.attachEvent) {
          form.attachEvent('onsubmit', handler);   
       }    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Replace it via JS with a button that calls your function

```
document.getElementById('cancel').parentNode.innerHTML = '<input type="button" onClick="myFunc()" value="replaced">';
window.myFunc = function() { alert('clicked'); return false; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e37nd/